# Shell script exits without evaluating if condition

Tags: scripts

I have the following commands in my shell script

```
#This line basically builds a source library
$BUILD_CMD $CONFIGFILES/$1.prj $BUILDFILESPATH 

if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
   echo "Build success\n"
   #do something here
else
   echo "Build Failure\n"
   #do something else here
fi
```

The build fails, however, the if condition is not evaluated and it does not echo a "Build Failure." The script just exits after the build command line.
Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have `set -e` or anything at the top of the script, do you?

Comment: What command is `$BUILD_CMD` using? You can also try putting `echo $?` after the $BUILD_CMD line, then you can test whether it using a different exit code.

Comment: @JasonConti I have not used a set -e in my script, but I think that is the issue. I explicitly wrote a set +e in my script, and now if the build command fails I get the "Build Failure" echo. I guess the $BUILD_CMD script would be doing a set -e as part of its code.

Comment: @Wilf $BUILD_CMD is the path to a python script which builds the project

Comment: You have to see inside the script if it is written to return an error code in case of failure. It's possible that the build fails but the shell that execute the script do not return any error code

Comment: @Hastur Yes, that is most likely the cause.

Comment: @Hastur if a script is not designed to return any code, doesn't bash/sh assign any return code, for example `0`? Or does the variable  `$?` just not exist?

Comment: It (`$?` and exit code) exists and it is 0. If different (it can be for many reasons) is a number different from 0. See `man bash` or [Bash Exit Codes With Special Meanings](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the building option fails but the python script do not return an error code.

So you need to use the  `sys.exit()` method in the python script. (The argument to that method is returned to the environment as the exit code).

Search the point in the script where you compile and from the code of the script you can find more easy to [raise an exception or to use an exit status.](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/exceptions-vs-status.html)

If you need to indicate an error in python you can [raise an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1152556/3569208) in the script or use the exit status.
Take an example from this [wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions)
)

You may find useful:

- [The try statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#try)
- [The exception statement](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions)
- [Bash Exit Codes With Special Meanings](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html)